# Scroll to Dropdown for better view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

This is my example site.

https://www.practo.com/bangalore/dermatologist-cosmetologist/anekal

In this when the "Book Appointment" button is clicked. A dropdown block appears and the page scrolls itself to top to make the block completely visible to the user.

I want to do the same in a website, so I need to know how its done. Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance...............

Comment: Search the source for `".book-toggle").live("click"` - that's the click event handler that does the scrolling.  (In Chrome, F12 then Ctrl + Shift + F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an anchor to the corresponding block, call the anchor when clicking the button. You could use a javascript scrollTo plugin for the animated effect. (as already mentioned.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for jQuery that covers that kind of functionality: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: I am already using a plugin, but it goes to the top and then comes back each time. I don't want it to be like that. I want something similar to the link.